# SAS: Save hotkeys

Tags: sas

I use a customized setup within the Enhanced Editor which sets Emacs-like bindings for many tasks.  For example, `Move cursor down` is assigned to `C-n`, `Move cursor left` is assigned to `C-b`, etc.

Unfortunately, whenever I need to reinstall SAS or use a different computer, I have to reassign everything by hand, a non-trivial process.  I know it's possible to export keyboard macros as `.kmf` files.  Are the assigned keys stored somewhere that I could back up?

I am using SAS 9.4 on Windows (otherwise I would just use Emacs).

Answer (score 2):

Your `sasuser.profile` catalog contains preferences and settings, amongst other things.  Copy that to the new sasuser folder and things should be as before.

Find your current SAS session `sasuser` path with `%put %sysfunc(pathname(sasuser));`

You can test this by creating a new SAS shortcut with a new -sasuser setting.

For example:

- create folder `c:\temp\sasuser`
- copy existing sasuser `profile.sas7bcat` file to the new `sasuser` folder
- create a new SAS shortcut

  - edit properties and append `-sasuser "c:\temp\sasuser"` to the target.
- open the shortcut

All your preferences and settings will be the same as you had in the old session.

Comment: The call `%put(%sysfunc(sasuser));` is invalid.  I believe you mean `%put(%sysfunc(pathname(sasuser));`

Comment: This appears to copy over the "Customize" and "Preference" setting only. Nothing related to the Enhanced Editor is transferred.  In particular, the hotkeys were not preserved nor settings such as Tab Size or Show Line Numbers.

Comment: This does transfer the KEYS for the Editor window (<DMKEYS>) and viewtable (<VT>).

Comment: Try migrating the items in your Windows registry to the new system.  `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAS Institute Inc.\Enhanced Editor\9.4\Editor Customizations\User Defined Keyboard Mappings`.  Windows RegEdit should have a context menu item for exporting.